# Android 7.1.1 kernel compile errors (tool chain)

Tags: android, c, linux-kernel, android-ndk

The build environment is ubuntu 16.04 with latest gcc  5.4.0 and GNU Make 3.82. My target is an am335x custom board which can run android 4.4. I am going to support it for android 7.1.1.

The project is fetched from google android manifest tag `android-7.1.1_r46` and the kernel is from msm tag `android-7.1.1_r0.63`. The cross compiler I am using is from `prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-eabi-4.8/bin`.

That is the environment information. I haven't installed the NDK or SDK yet because I saw the api level for android 7.1.1 is 25 while the newest NDK only support up to 24, so I get a bit confused what to do.

If I run the command: `m -j8 uboot linux`
The uboot compiles fine, but there are a lot of errors when compiling the linux kernel.

```
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/prm_common.c: In function 'omap_prcm_register_chain_handler':
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/arch/arm/mach-omap2/prm_common.c:293:2: warning: passing argument 2 of 'irq_set_chained_handler' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
error, forbidden warning: prm_common.c:293
make[2]: *** [arch/arm/mach-omap2/prm_common.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/mach-omap2] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/sysctl_binary.c:141:13: error: 'KERN_BOOT_REASON' undeclared here (not in a function)
  { CTL_INT, KERN_BOOT_REASON,  "boot_reason" },
             ^
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/sysctl_binary.c:528:13: error: 'NET_IPV6_ACCEPT_RA_PREFIX_ROUTE' undeclared here (not in a function)
  { CTL_INT, NET_IPV6_ACCEPT_RA_PREFIX_ROUTE, "accept_ra_prefix_route" },
             ^
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/sysctl_binary.c:528:2: error: initializer element is not constant
  { CTL_INT, NET_IPV6_ACCEPT_RA_PREFIX_ROUTE, "accept_ra_prefix_route" },
  ^
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/sysctl_binary.c:528:2: error: (near initialization for 'bin_net_ipv6_conf_var_table[24].ctl_name')
make[2]: *** [kernel/sysctl_binary.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [kernel] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/media/yangjiel/disk2/android'
```

If I drop the lines in that file which causing this error, the error above is resolved but I would get another

```
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/cgroup.c: In function 'subsys_cgroup_allow_attach':
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/cgroup.c:2138:37: error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'kuid_t' and 'kuid_t')
   if (current != task && cred->euid != tcred->uid &&
                                     ^
/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel/kernel/cgroup.c:2139:18: error: invalid operands to binary != (have 'kuid_t' and 'kuid_t')
       cred->euid != tcred->suid)
                  ^
make[2]: *** [kernel/cgroup.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
  CC      kernel/trace/power-traces.o
  CC      kernel/trace/rpm-traces.o
  CC      kernel/trace/trace_probe.o
  LD      kernel/trace/libftrace.o
  LD      kernel/trace/built-in.o
make[1]: *** [kernel] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/media/yangjiel/disk2/android/kernel'
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/media/yangjiel/disk2/android'
```

There are more errors behind.

I have googled around and most of the people say this is a tool chain problem. But I don't find a lot of instruction about how to install the tool chain properly especially for 7.1.1. There seems to be no tool chain needed for the android 4.4 kernel. I fetch the custom android 4.4 kernel and it compiles fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem above is because I downloaded a wrong version of Android kernel. What I downloaded is `https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/msm/+/android-7.1.1_r0.63`, and this is kernel v3.10.

Obviously this is not for Android 7.1.1 (which should be using kernel v4.4). So when I am trying to compile "old" kernel with the "new" cross compiler from the prebuilt, it generated whole bunch errors that the "old" compiler won't. I end up using the kernel from `https://android.googlesource.com/kernel/common/+/upstream-linux-4.4.y` `upstream-linux-4.4.y` branch, it is compatible with Android 7.0 to 7.1.2.

I have no idea why google name it as `android-7.1.1_r0.63`, but that definitely not for Android 7.1.1 to use. Hope nobody has the same problem as I did.